# How to compare two arrays in JavaScript? But the key is a string

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner in JavaScript, I've two arrays.

I must compare and find out if there are repeated values between them. I am not able to do this because the key of array is a string. As you can see:

```
[
  { "species-name": "Cana-de-açucar"},
  { "species-name": "Citros"},
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Feijão"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "Fruticultura"},
  { "species-name": "Girassol"},
  { "species-name": "Hortaliças"},
  { "species-name": "Mandioca"}
]
```

And the other array:

```
[
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"}
]
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _“because the key of array is a string”_ - please explain _why_ you are unable to do it, specifically because of that. If you don’t know how to iterate over the properies of an object, then that is the first thing you should go read up on.

Comment: you want to know which of the entries from the second array are allthough in the first?

Comment: The key of the array is not a string. Arrays always have integer for index. You just need to iterate over one array and then for object inside that array check if it's inside the other array using `Array.indexOf` method. Crude but will get you there.

Comment: What did you try? What do you want to do if thee are repeated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple solution to achieve what you need:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { "species-name": "Cana-de-açucar"},
  { "species-name": "Citros"},
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Feijão"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "Fruticultura"},
  { "species-name": "Girassol"},
  { "species-name": "Hortaliças"},
  { "species-name": "Mandioca"}
];

const arr2 = [
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "Non duplicate value" }
];

const extractValue = ({ 'species-name': speciesName }) => speciesName;

const duplicateValues = arr1
    .map(extractValue)
    .filter(x => arr2
        .map(extractValue)
        .includes(x)
    );

console.log(duplicateValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the intersection of two arrays, then you will have to see which one is longer. The longest one will be filtered, and the shorter one will be used as an array to search within.

```js
const first = [
  { "species-name": "Cana-de-açucar"},
  { "species-name": "Citros"},
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Feijão"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "Fruticultura"},
  { "species-name": "Girassol"},
  { "species-name": "Hortaliças"},
  { "species-name": "Mandioca"}
]

const second = [
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"}
]

const intersection = (longer, shorter, key) => {
  let tmp;
  if (shorter.length > longer.length) {
    tmp = shorter, shorter = longer, longer = tmp; // Swap
  }
  const vals = shorter.map(entry => entry[key]);
  return longer.filter(entry => vals.find(v => v === entry[key]));
}

const key = 'species-name';
const third = intersection(first, second, key);

console.log(third);
console.log(third.flatMap(Object.values));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: @EugenSunic I was attempting to document through code. This is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and OP is a beginner. I did just update it to explicitly utilize the key.

Comment: Nice, you could also shorten `e => Object.values(e)` to `Object.values`  since it's somewhat a static method. Congrats for your 1337th answer btw.

Comment: @GuerricP Good catch, but note that only works on unbound function calls.

Comment: That's what I meant when saying "static method" (doesn't use `this`)

Answer (score 0):

Object-structure-agnostic (without a need to deconstruct an object use):

```js
const arr1 = [
  { "species-name": "Cana-de-açucar"},
  { "species-name": "Citros"},
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Feijão"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "Fruticultura"},
  { "species-name": "Girassol"},
  { "species-name": "Hortaliças"},
  { "species-name": "Mandioca"}
];

const arr2 = [
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "not-a-duplicate"},
];

const arr2String = JSON.stringify(arr2);
const duplicates = arr1.filter(x => arr2String.includes(JSON.stringify(x)));
console.log(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate through the first array, and only return if you find that value in arr2. Then use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in the new filtered array, to just return values rather than objects.

```
const arr1 = [
  { "species-name": "Cana-de-açucar"},
  { "species-name": "Citros"},
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Feijão"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"},
  { "species-name": "Fruticultura"},
  { "species-name": "Girassol"},
  { "species-name": "Hortaliças"},
  { "species-name": "Mandioca"}
];

const arr2 = [
  { "species-name": "Eucalipto"},
  { "species-name": "Flor de Corte"},
  { "species-name": "Floresta"}
];

const duplicateValues = arr1.filter(e => {
    return arr2.find(i => i['species-name'] === e['species-name'])
}).map(duplicate => duplicate['species-name']);

console.log(duplicateValues);
// expected output: ["Eucalipto", "Flor de Corte", "Floresta"]
```